# Stuck on Setting Up Webpack with React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've tried looking at the docs and searching online, but I'm having a really hard time configuring webpack with my React project. I'm trying to use webpack-dev-server. When I do the yarn start command, this is what I see in the browser.

[Image of what I see in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHvcS.png)

I have no idea where to go from here. This is what my webpack.config.js looks like.

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/components/app.js',

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./dist"
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Here is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "react-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer build/static/js/main.*",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why dont you use cli ?

Comment: npm install -g create-react-app

Comment: create-react-app react-portfolio

Comment: where is your index.html?

Comment: @bianca-m you are trying to serve the project from "dist" folder, which is used for deployment I guess. If you'll check your "dist" folder, you'll see that probably is empty. Try to change in webpack.config -> contentBase from "./dist" to "/"

Comment: Where is your `index.html` file? Webpack will only bundle the code into a .js file. The rest is up to you.

Comment: @furcicm there's a bundle.js file in the dist folder, and I tried removing contentBase altogether, as some examples I've been looking at don't even reference contentBase in their config. My index.html is in "public"

Comment: @nbkhope webpack-dev-server is serving your app, so you will need index.html.

Comment: @bianca-m did you try this to set devServer as this? -> 
 
devServer: { contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '.') }

Comment: You may also want to check out https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/ which can automatically generate the index.html for you.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, everyone! I just ended up going back through and doing the cli. It's not really necessary for me to tweak webpack configurations at this point.